# Meteor: Need explanation about json objects

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to make variable from helper working in template. I'm using api:

```
//client

Template.hello.helpers({
    fooVar: function(){
        return Meteor.call('checkApi', function(error, results) {
            re = JSON.parse(results.content); //returns json(see json response)
            console.log(re[0].foo); // returns right value
            console.log(re); //returns json
            return re[0].foo //not working
        });
    } 
  });
```

server:

```
//server
Meteor.methods({
    checkApi: function() {
        this.unblock();
        return Meteor.http.call("GET", "https://someApi/getData",{
            headers: {
                "Auth": "myToken"
            }
        });
    }
  });
```

My template:

```
...
{{>hello}}
<template name="hello">
{{fooVar}} //not working
</template>
```

JSON response:

```
[
  {
    "FirstValue": "I'm the first value",
    "SecondValue": "I'm the second value"
  }
]
```

I'f i'm using this(on client helper):
`console.log(results.data)` and i'm see an object in console with right fieilds, but this:

```
console.log(results.data.FirstValue) is not working
```

This working nice:

```
 re = JSON.parse(results.content); //returns json(see json response)
 console.log(re[0].foo); // returns right value
```

But in template 'fooVar' variable is undefined in console.
Please explain what should i do to make this working it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use helper to display Meteor.call('...') value. Check https://atmospherejs.com/simple/reactive-method or do something like

```
Template.hello.onCreated(function () {
    Meteor.call('checkApi', function(error, results) {
        re = JSON.parse(results.content);

        Session.set('methodReturnValue', re[0].foo);
    });
});

Template.hello.helpers({
    fooVar: function(){
        return Session.get('methodReturnValue');
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it working. But what should i do to using object(from re.data) in my template?

Comment: Hmmm, It looks like results.data is an array so you should iterate through it or get the first object like results.data[0].FirstValue